# Cannot show products (courses) in my MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i need help with my MVC Project. 
My page will shown avaible Courses so i need to show Courses on page 
my code looks like this but doesnt work
i try to show properties for Courses from CourseViewModel in

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new List<CourseViewModel>();

    CourseViewModel Courses = new CourseViewModel();

    Courses = new CourseViewModel();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

would be so glad if someone could help me..

Comment: Well you seem to be returning an empty list and not doing anything with the `CourseViewModel` you create, but it's hard to know what you _should_ be doing.

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing? As @DStanley mentioned, you are returning a empty ViewModel.

Comment: @garfbradaz , my courseviewmodel looks like this      public virtual List<CourseViewModel> Courses { get; set; }

        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string CoursePlace { get; set; }
        public string CourseLevel { get; set; }
        public string CourseDate { get; set; }
        public string CourseDescription { get; set; }
        public string CourseBookUrl { get; set; }                                             how should i then connect actionresult with viewmodel to show Courses?

Comment: @JPo: Update your question with the code from the comment please, it s not easy to read.

Comment: @garfbradaz , how should i connect my viewmodel with actionresult so my Courses can will be displayed?

Comment: Well you need to load your view model with data first!

Comment: but i have data in my view model? oh man im new in this so i cannot really understand what you mean

Comment: @garfbradaz      if you understand me

Comment: @JPo - you're correctly adding your viewmodel to the actionresult. What you're not doing, however, is putting anything in your viewmodel. It's clearly an empty list. If you're having trouble with that, then maybe you should watch more C# tutorials, or google how to create objects and add them to lists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class looks like this based on your comments

```
public class CourseViewModel {
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CoursePlace { get; set; }
    public string CourseLevel { get; set; }
    public string CourseDate { get; set; }
    public string CourseDescription { get; set; }
    public string CourseBookUrl { get; set; }
}
```

You populate your list to pass as the viewmodel for your view

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var viewModel = new List<CourseViewModel>();

    //Either get the viewmodels from a data source or add them yourself

    var course = new CourseViewModel() {
        CourseId = 1,
        CourseName = "Maths 101",
        CoursePlace = "Some class room",
        CourseLevel = "1",
        CourseDate = "",
        //..populate other properties
    };

    viewModel.Add(course);

    //repeat to add more courses


    return View(viewModel);
}
```

In your view you specify what type the view model is

```
@model List<CourseViewModel>
```

and you can traverse the model and display the details.

```
@foreach (var course in Model) {
    <div>@course.CourseName</div>
    <!--other details you want to display-->
}
```